# Pandas: Conditionally insert rows into DataFrame while iterating through rows in the middle

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and need to insert rows in the middle based on a condition, if the condition is met, I need to add rows based on previous and next row values.
So far I have this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    last_row = df.iloc[index-1]
    next_row = df.iloc[index+1]

    new_row = {
    'SystemID' : last_row.SystemID,
    'StartDateTime' : last_row.EndDateTime,
    'EndDateTime' : next_row.StartDateTime,
    'Date' : last_row.Date,
    'Duration':0,
    'EventCodeType':"PL",
    'Shift':last_row.Shift,
    'ProductCode':last_row.ProductCode,
    'Machine&Fault':"Producing"
    }
    new_row = {k:v for k,v in new_row.items()}
    if index == last:
        break
    else:
        if index != 0 :
            #condition 
            if (df.iloc[index]['StartDateTime'] != df.iloc[index - 1]['EndDateTime']):
                df.loc[index+1] = new_row # This line is giving error


    continue
```

But when I'm trying to insert row(last line of code), it is throwing an error
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds for the code(next_row = df.iloc[index+1])

the data looks like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Update:**
I used the below logic as suggested in one of the answers

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        if index == df.shape[0]:
            break
        else:           
            last_row = df.iloc[index-1]
            next_row = df.iloc[index]
            new_row = {
            'SystemID' : last_row.SystemID,
            'StartDateTime' : last_row.EndDateTime,
            'EndDateTime' : next_row.StartDateTime,
            'Date' : last_row.Date,
            'Duration':0 ,
            'EventCodeType':"PL",
            'Shift':last_row.Shift,
            'ProductCode':last_row.ProductCode,
            'Machine&Fault':"Producing"
            }
            new_row = {k:v for k,v in new_row.items()}
            if index != 0 and index!=df.shape[0]:
                if (df.iloc[index]['StartDateTime'] != df.iloc[index - 1]['EndDateTime']):
                    df1 = df1.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

            continue
    except:
        continue
```

Put the code in a try catch exception and append the new rows in a new dataframe and concat the two dataframes
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFVBT.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a row beyond the dataframe's scope (size/capacity, so to say). You can get the the size of dataframe by using `dataframe.shape()`.

If you need to, you would have to extend the index of the dataframe using `set_index()` when you try to add a row at the end/after the last row. This should solve your issue.

You could also use `dataframe.append()` to add new rows.

Another possible solution would be to use integer slicing with `iloc`. `iloc` doesn't give an error with slicing, but again, going beyond the scope of the dataframe would still be an issue you have to fix before appending anyhting.

Comment: That's certainly the immediate issue, however, I wonder if there is an elegant way to do this sort of upsampling given a condition that depends on previous and next row.

Comment: @Norwegian Salmon   I added a code to break the loop when the last row is encountered, it is still giving me the error                                                                                                                  
` for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == df.shape[0]:
        break
    else:`

Comment: @RobertSmith I think index splitting would be more elegant once the conditions are met. There are similar solutions already available for that.

Comment: @KGPVertiv It's not just specific to the last row, though. What I meant to say is, adding a row to a df beyond the scope will give an error because the dataframe is fixed for that size/shape. It will become a very memory intensive task as a new df will be created each time, iirc.

Comment: @NorwegianSalmon It is a manufacturing dataset and only includes data with stops information. I want to add data where the lines function normally for time series analysis. I want to add the rows in the middle for this use case for sequential analysis, is there a way I can do that efficiently, since this is a huge dataset.

Comment: @KGPVertiv The most efficient way you could do is by using a combination of `resample` and `resetindex`. Creating a dataframe for the missing values and then concatenating the two dataframes would be the most efficient approach. 
Please have a look at the documentation of the two along with solutions already provided by members on SO.

Comment: @NorwegianSalmon thanks for the comment! I will take a look at it, can you please tell me how would I insert the new dataframe into the old dataframe with the rows being in that order?

Comment: You can make the StartDateTime/EndDateTime as the index and use 
`df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(by='<index>')`